# Potential automorphy of abelian varieties

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $\mathbb Q$. One could ask

(1) is there a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$ such that the L-function $L(A/K,s)$ is the L-function of an automorphic form?

or

(2) is there a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$ such that, for every finite extension $K \subset K'$, the L-function  $L(A/{K'},s)$ of $A$ over $K'$ is the L-function of an automorphic form?

Questions: 
(i) It seems potential automorphic refers to (1). Is that correct?

(ii) Does (1) imply (2) under the assumption of the Artin conjecture?

For elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$, modularity is equivalent to a non-constant map from the modular curve to the given elliptic curve and hence a cycle on the product of the modular curve and the elliptic curve.

(iii) If an abelian variety is automorphic, then is an appropriate algebraic cycle expected on the product of a Shimura variety and the given abelian variety?

Comment: Could you tell what results you assume about $\rho : \text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K) \to \text{Aut}(T_{\ell}(A))$ ?

Comment: Why do you think the Artin conjecture is relevant?

Comment: @reuns: No assumptions on $\rho$.

Comment: No assumptions but plenty of results have been proven, so please remind us (for those who know Artin L-functions better than abelian varieties)

Comment: @WillSawin: Because the L-function of $A$ over any Galois extension $K'$ of $K$ will be a product of the L-function $L(A \otimes \chi, s)$ where $\chi$ is an irreducible representation of the finite Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(K'/K)$. So it seemed the Artin conjecture for $\chi$ might be relevant here.

Comment: @reuns: the question is for general $A$. But suppose $K$ is totally real and $A$ is an abelian surface over $K$ with everywhere good reduction. So we can assume $\rho$ is unramified outside of primes dividing $\ell$.

Comment: @guest I don't see how the Artin conjecture for $L(\chi,s)$ implies anything about the tensor product $L$-function $L(A \otimes \chi,s)$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Oh, so maybe it is not relevant. That raises the question: are (1) and (2) related at all?

Answer (score 2):

(i) is correct.

(ii) has nothing to do with Artin's conjecture I believe. It is known that (1) implies (2) in the case $K'/K$ solvable. This is the so-called solvable base change, solved by Arthur and Clozel in the 1980's, and it really has nothing to do with abelian varieties. The general non-solvable case is wide-open.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just to make sure, you are saying that the relation between (1) and (2) is base-change?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $A$ is automorphic and $\chi$ is automorphic then from the Rankin-Selberg (Jacquet, Piatetski-Shapiro, Shalika) you know that the L-function $L(A \times \chi,s)$ is meromorphic and satisfies the expected functional equation. That gives a weak form of (ii). (I don't know the answer to your other questions.)

Comment: Do you mean "the L-function associated to  $ A $ (resp.  $ \chi $ )" instead of  $ A $ and  $ \chi $ themselves ?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, it is obvious that both statements have the same meanings and there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @Moreofacomment: Thanks for your response. Could you please point me to a reference for this?